# How to solve MongoDB error "Too many open files" without root permission

Tags: database, mongodb, permissions, ulimit

Trying to insert several JSON files to MongoDB collections using shell script as following,

```
#!/bin/bash

NUM=50000
for ((i=o;i<NUM;i++))
do
    mongoimport --host localhost --port 27018 -u 'admin' -p 'password' --authenticationDatabase 'admin' -d random_test -c tri_${i} /home/test/json_files/json_${i}.csv --jsonArray
done
```

after several successful adding, these errors were shown on terminal

```
Failed: connection(localhost:27017[-3]), incomplete read of message header: EOF
error connecting to host: could not connect to server: 
server selection error: server selection timeout, 
current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: 
[{ Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, 
State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : 
dial tcp [::1]:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
```

And below the eoor messages from mongo.log, that said too many open files, can I somehow limit the thread number? or what should I do to fix it?? Thanks a lot!

```
2020-07-21T11:13:33.613+0200 E  STORAGE  [conn971] WiredTiger error (24) [1595322813:613873][53971:0x7f7c8d228700], WT_SESSION.create: __posix_directory_sync, 151: /home/mongodb/bin/data/db/index-969--7295385362343345274.wt: directory-sync: Too many open files Raw: [1595322813:613873][53971:0x7f7c8d228700], WT_SESSION.create: __posix_directory_sync, 151: /home/mongodb/bin/data/db/index-969--7295385362343345274.wt: directory-sync: Too many open files
2020-07-21T11:13:33.613+0200 E  STORAGE  [conn971] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1595322813:613892][53971:0x7f7c8d228700], WT_SESSION.create: __wt_panic, 490: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: [1595322813:613892][53971:0x7f7c8d228700], WT_SESSION.create: __wt_panic, 490: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2020-07-21T11:13:33.613+0200 F  -        [conn971] Fatal Assertion 50853 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 414
2020-07-21T11:13:33.613+0200 F  -        [conn971]

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

checking the open file limit by `ulimit -n` shows `1024`. Then I tried to alter the limit by `ulimit -n 50000`, but the accout that I used for the remote server doesn't have permissions to do that, can I somehow close the file once the importing is done or is there any other way to alter the open file limit without root permission needed? Thanks a lot!

Env: Redhat, mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The reason why resource limits exist is to limit how much resources non-privileged users (which yours is) can consume. You need to reconfigure the system to adjust this which requires root privileges.